# saveAll not working with hasMany through (Join Model)

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to do this with last 2.x CakePHP version

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IylLu.png

Without education_id in projects_students table works perfectly. But doesn't work with education_id.

this is my implementation with education_id:

**ProjectsStudent.php**

```
    class ProjectsStudent extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className'    => 'Project',
        'foreignKey'   => 'project_id'
    ),
   'Student' => array(
        'className'    => 'Student',
        'foreignKey'   => 'student_id'
    )
);
```

**Student.php**

```
public $hasMany = array('ProjectsStudent');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Education' => array(
            'className' => 'Student',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_students',
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'project_id',
        ),
    );
```

**Project.php**

```
public $belongsTo = 'Status';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Doc' => array(
            'className' => 'Doc',
            'joinTable' => 'docs',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        ),
        'History' => array(
            'className' => 'History',
            'joinTable' => 'history',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        ),
        'ProjectsStudent'
    );
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Student' => array(
            'className' => 'Student',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_students',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'student_id',
        ),
        'Professor' => array(
            'className' => 'Professor',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_professors',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'professor_id',
        ),
        'Education' => array(
            'className' => 'Education',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_educations',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'education_id',
        ),
    );
```

**ProjectsController.php**

```
$data = array(
                'Project' => array(
                    'id' => $id, 
                    'status_id' => 5,
                    'Student' => array($this->Auth->user('id'))),
                'History' => array(
                    array(
                        'action' => 'update -> status 5',
                        'student_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                    )
                ),
                'ProjectsStudent' => array(array(
                    'education_id' => "5")) 
            );
            $this->Project->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true))
```

**Output error:**

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '109' for key 'PRIMARY'

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `tfg`.`projects_students` (`project_id`, `education_id`) VALUES (109, 5)

I think CakePHP is trying 2 inserts, with (`project_id`, `student_id`) and with (`project_id`, `education_id`)

I want just one input like INSERT INTO `tfg`.`projects_students` (`project_id`,`student_id`,`education_id`) VALUES (109, 1, 5)

Thanks in advance, sorry for my english.

***---SOLUTION---***

```
$data = array(
            'Project' => array(
                'id' => $id, 
                'status_id' => 5,
                'Student' => array($this->Auth->user('id'))),
            'History' => array(
                array(
                    'action' => 'update -> status 5',
                    'student_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                )
            ),

        );

        $this->Project->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));

        $this->Project->ProjectsStudent->updateAll(
                array('education_id' => $this->Auth->user('education')),
            array('project_id' => $this->Project->id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have setup the projects_students table to use `project_id` as the primary key. The primary key needs to be unique whereas the `project_id` foreign key is likely to be duplicated (as appears to be happening for you). The join table should be at least:-

```
id (int)
project_id (int)
student_id (int)
```

Where id is the primary key (with auto increment enabled).

Comment: You don't need a id field in the join table to achieve this.